# How does 1 2 3 come at the end?

Tags: java, recursion

In this program, if the user enters the number 3, the o/p will be 3 2 1 1 2 3 , I understood how 3 2 1 came, but I didn't understand how 1 2 3   came at the end.

```
class GFG{ 
static void printFun(int test) 
{ 
    if (test < 1) 
        return; 
    else
    { 
        System.out.printf("%d ",test); 
        printFun(test-1); // statement 2 
        System.out.printf("%d ",test); 
        return; 
    } 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    int test = 3; 
    printFun(test); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Look at your second `System.out.printf`. By the way, the language is called `Java`, not `JAVA`.

Comment: That is what I am not getting, how does the second printf statement work?

Comment: It should print 3 2 1 1 2 3 , not 1 2 3 3 2 1 from what I can see, can you check?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry it prints 3 2 1 1 2 3, How does the second printf statement help the program in printing 1 2 3, is what i am not getting..

Comment: It's a recursive call to the same function. It calls the function again with `2` instead of `3`

Comment: The first statement prints "3 2 1", the second one prints "1 2 3". They work exactly the same way. One prints "on the way into the recursion", one prints "on the way back out". Best to write down the call sequence step by step on a piece of paper. Or use a debugger to step through line by line.

Comment: Function call are maintained by stack. Statement above Recursive call is a PUSH operation and after recursive call is POP operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to trace through recursive functions is by expanding every recursive call, like a math expression.

First we start with

```
printFun(3)
```

That expands to:

```
print(3) // I have shortened System.out.printf here to just "print" to remove the noise
printFun(2)
print(3)
```

We still have a recursive call (`printFun(2)`), so let's expand that.

```
print(3)
print(2)
printFun(1)
print(2)
print(3)
```

Continue expanding:

```
print(3)
print(2)
print(1)
printFun(0)
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
```

And one last time (since `printFun(0)` doesn't do anything, we just remove it):

```
print(3)
print(2)
print(1)
print(1)
print(2)
print(3)
```

Oh look! That will produce the output `3 2 1 1 2 3`!

Answer (score 3):

Ok - nature of recursions. Recursions put their calls on stacks which is built bottom-up. Whenever a member is recalled from the stack it is to be taken from the top till we reach the bottom again. Lets go through it line-per-line:

function is called 1st time with 3

function writes: 3 and calls itself with 2 - function halts (right after statement2) and waits for execution

function writes: 2 and calls itself with 1 - function halts and waits for execution

function writes: 1 and calls itself with 0 - call returns immediately because of value 0. Time to reduce the caller-stack and continue halted functions.

last function halt is reactivated (it was 1) and writes: 1 - then function returns

last function halt is reactivated (it was 2) and writes: 2 - then function returns

last function halt is reactivated (it was 3) and writes: 3 - then function returns

program stops.

Therefore you get the line of numbers you wrote.

Answer (score 3):

The recursive invocation  `printFun(test-1)` make the method goes on to invoke it in this way :

```
printFun(3); // original
printFun(2);
printFun(1);
printFun(0);
```

Arriving at this time it doesn't perform any other recursive call because of the condition encountered for `printFun(0)`.
The current call that is the last recursive call (`printFun(0)`) goes on with `return`. Then the execution goes up to the caller of `printFun(0)` that is `printFun(1)` that executes the second `System.out.printf("%d ",test);`  statement and it `returns`.
Then same logic :  The execution goes up to the method that invoked that, that is `printFun(2)`.
And that goes on to go up until the initial one invocation.

You can see calls in this way :

```
printFun(3)
   printFun(2)
      printFun(1)
          printFun(0)
                   -- No more recursive call, execution goes on where we are
          printFun(0)
      printFun(1)
   printFun(2)
printFun(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

I added some print commands to help you understand this.

```
class GFG{
    static int count = 1;  
    static String combined = "";
    static void printFun(int test){ 
        System.out.println("No of times Function printFun has been called : " + count);
        count = count + 1;
        if (test < 1)
            return;
        else{
            System.out.println("Adding " + test + " to combined string");
            combined = combined + test;
            printFun(test-1); // statement 2 
            System.out.println("Returning to the previous call of printFun");
            combined = combined + test;
            System.out.println("Adding " + test  + " to combined string");
            return;
       }
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        int test = 3;
        printFun(test);
        System.out.println(combined);
    }
}
```

I'm printing out the combined string at the end, the print statements should indicate how the function gets recursively called.

Answer (score 0):

Function calls are maintained by stack. All local variables of the function corresponds to the function call instance. Each function call instance is maintained in Stack.

Statement above Recursive call is a PUSH operation and after recursive call is POP operation.

Hence its 
(Statement before recursive call)

print(3) PUSH(3),  print (2) PUSH(2), print(1) PUSH(1)

followed by
(Statement after recursive call).

POP(1) print(1), POP(2) print(2) , POP(3) print(3)

Hence output is 3 2 1 1 2 3